# Function that return undefined in node.js. Inside the function I have mongoDB.connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to make function for my project in the service. This service need to check is user exists in my database, **but my function(this function is checking) inside the class return undefined**.

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "here I paste url to my databse(everything is good here)";

class CheckService {

    isUserExists(username) {
        mongoDB.connect(url, (error, connection) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error", '\n', error);
                throw error;
            }

            const query = {name: username};

            const db = connection.db("users");

          const result =  db.collection("users").find(query).toArray(
                function findUser(error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                    const arr = [];
                    if (result.value === arr.value) {
                        console.log(false);
                        connection.close();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        console.log(true);
                        console.log(arr);
                        console.log(result);
                        connection.close();
                        return true;
                    }

                });

           console.log(result);


        });
    }

}

module.exports = new CheckService();
```

I imported my service to another service:

```
const checkService = require('./check.service');
```

After this, I invoked my function from my service like this:

```
console.log('function:',checkService.isUserExists(username));
```

I expected good result, but function doesn't return, that I want, unfortunately.

**Please help!**

Comment: Your function needs to `return result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your function

1. it doesn't return anything
2. `toArray()` is a promise, so your console.log probably just prints a promise.

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
class CheckService {

    async isUserExists(username) {
        const connection = await mongoDB.connect(url);
        const query = {name: username};
        const db = connection.db("users");
        const result = await db.collection("users").find(query).toArray();
        connection.close();
        return result.length !== 0;
    }

}
```

You'd then invoke it with something like

```
await new CheckService().isUserExists(username);
```

Though, it's worth noting that you probably don't need `toArray` and instead could use `findOne` or even `count()` since all you care about is existence. I probably also wouldn't instantiate a new connection each time (but that's not super relevant)

Comment: How to export this class?

Comment: the same way you did before - `module.exports = new CheckService();`, or you could do `module.exports = CheckService` and use `new CheckService()` in a different file

Comment: Thank you. I used your code(without any changes). But my function returns Promise { <pending> } when I call it.  Can you explain what's wrong here?

Comment: somewhere you aren't awaiting the promise - can you show me exactly how you invoke `isUserExists`?

Comment: I imported my service to another service: const checkService = require('./check.service'); After this, I invoked my function from my service like this:  console.log('function:', checkService.isUserExists(username));

Comment: That is your problem - you need to use `console.log('function:', await checkService.isUserExists(username));`

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything works!

Answer (score 0):

2 things wrong here. Firstly the first comment is correct. You're only logging the result and not passing back to the caller. Secondly, a quick peek at the mongo docs shows that retrieval methods are promises. You need to make the function async and add awaits where needed.

Mongo:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/

Promises:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise